# Connecting to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

I have imported a database over to MySQL in phpMyAdmin. I am performing my work locally using WAMPSERVER (localhost).

Before I imported the database, I was getting the error Database not found. Now that I have added the database in localhost. I am getting the following error in the browser when I go to index.php

**SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.**

Here are some details about the config file, if it helps:

I haven't changed the .htaccess file. I do however have a config file that looks like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="127.0.0.1")
{
    $DB_HOST="localhost";
    $DB_USER="root";
    $DB_PASS="";
    $DB_NAME="dbName";
    $site_url="http://localhost/folder/";
    $doc_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/";
}
else
{
    $DB_HOST="localhost";
    $DB_USER="root";
    $DB_PASS="password";
    $DB_NAME="dbName";
    if($_SERVER["HTTPS"]=="on")
        $site_url="weburl";
    else
        $site_url="weburl";
    $doc_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

Comment: You will need to show some code. Who exactly is causing this error message to show?

Comment: are you running as a https:// ? It's quite obvious that you will not have SSL certificate for your localhost.

Comment: Try going to http://localhost/index.php

Comment: I tried: https://localhost:8080/MyFolder/index.php

That doesn't work.

Comment: for some reason when I try it without https, it puts it there anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `https://` when you are running it in you local machine. Because you can't have SSL certificate for your local machine, isn't it?

Try: `http://localhost/myfolder/index.php` instead.

Comment: I haven't changed the .htaccess file. I do however have a config file that looks like this:

<?php
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="127.0.0.1")
{
 $DB_HOST="localhost";
 $DB_USER="root";
 $DB_PASS="";
 $DB_NAME="dbName";
 $site_url="http://localhost/folder/";
 $doc_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/";
}
else
{
 $DB_HOST="localhost";
 $DB_USER="root";
 $DB_PASS="password";
 $DB_NAME="dbName";
 if($_SERVER["HTTPS"]=="on")
  $site_url="weburl";
 else
  $site_url="weburl";
 $doc_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

Comment: Does 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' actually refer to a folder called DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: it gives your directory root path.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have `https` on.

And you're having issue going to `http://` since you already went to `https://` in your browser (Chrome is my guess). Try clearing your visited sites or history and it will work just fine. Or you may try it in another browser.

Also, it is possible that you may have edited an `.htacess` file to redirect or installed a php framework with `https` on.

Comment: I haven't changed the .htaccess file. I do however have a config file that looks like this:



<?php
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="127.0.0.1")
{
 $DB_HOST="localhost";
 $DB_USER="root";
 $DB_PASS="";
 $DB_NAME="dbName";
 $site_url="http://localhost/folder/";
 $doc_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/";
}
else
{
 $DB_HOST="localhost";
 $DB_USER="root";
 $DB_PASS="password";
 $DB_NAME="dbName";
 if($_SERVER["HTTPS"]=="on")
  $site_url="weburl";
 else
  $site_url="weburl";
 $doc_root=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish. Do you want it to be a https connection or not?